# How to interpret the result of format(n, 'c') beyond ASCII?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the following example:

```
format(97, 'c')
format(6211, 'c')
```

The first outputs `'a'` which is obviously correct; however, the second outputs `'C'` which I don't understand why.

The [string format specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) states that:

> 'c': Character. Converts the integer to the corresponding unicode character before printing.

So shouldn't `6211` be mapped to its Unicode character which is `我` in Chinese?

Related sysinfo: CPython 2.7.10, on Fedora 22.

Comment: Note that Unicode code points are hexadecimal, not decimal; 'a' is U+0061, which is decimal 97, and '我' is U+6211, which is decimal 25105. Decimal 6211 would be U+1843 MONGOLIAN LETTER TODO LONG VOWEL SIGN `ᡃ`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeing [Issue 7267 - format method: c presentation type broken in 2.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue7267) .

The issue is that `format(int, 'c')` internally calls `int.__format__('c')` , and it returns an str value (bytes in Python 2.x) , hence it would always be in the range (0, 256) . Hence for value like 256, it goes round back to `0`. Example -

```
>>> format(256,'c')
'\x00'
```

According to the issue, they say the fix would be to use Python 3 , where strings are unicode , and thus issue is not there in Python 3.x .

The only workaround I can think of would be to use [`unichr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) instead -

```
>>> unichr(0x6211)
u'\u6211'
>>> print(unichr(0x6211))
我
```

Though please do note, `6211` is an integer and its not the unicode character you are looking for, it maps to [`0x1843`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1843/index.htm). What you are looking for is `0x6211` , which is an hexadecimal value, which maps to [`我`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6211/index.htm) , i.e `format(0x6211,'c')` in Python 3.x  .

Comment: for detecting the `0x6211` for `我` +1.